# React Native ScrollView

Tags: react-native, react-native-animatable

I am new to react native, have a requirement in which I have to scroll images in arc, like scrolling over a semi circular arc, is it possible to design the same using scrollview, can anyone just drop me some hints ? , I am also trying out react-native-snap-carousel library

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).